# Javascript HMAC(using Postman) and Python HMAC not returning same hash

Tags: javascript, python, api, postman

I am able to successfully connect to an API using Postman. Below is the pre-request script on Postman:

```
postman.clearGlobalVariable("hmac");
var secretKey = "dummykey"
var sha1 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(request.data, secretKey);
var base = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(sha1);
postman.setGlobalVariable("hmac", base);
```

I am trying to generate the same hash value as above in python

```
import base64
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import binascii

key = "dummykey".encode(encoding='utf-8')
message = '{"ID": "abc123","Name": "dummyname", "TimestampUtc":"2017-10-10T14:03:17.637"}'.encode(encoding='utf-8') #some dummy json

digest = hmac.new(key, message, hashlib.sha1).digest()
hash_value = base64.b64encode(binascii.hexlify(bytearray(digest)))
print(hash_value.decode('utf-8')
```

but I am getting a different hash_value in python(ZmU0MDUzMzI2NWNiODVjMGQ4YmRmOWM5ZWMzYzZhM2Y2ZTdlNTNjNQ==). I am unable to connect to the API in python. How do I make sure to get the same hash value in python?

Comment: What hash value was it giving? Also I think it needs to be `b"dummykey"`

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I have included the encoding, and the hash value that the python code is generating

Comment: It's because you're trying to base64 encode the hex representation of that, which I don't think is intended (you probably meant to base64 encode the digest itself). However, when I pop your data into a web hmac calculator, I got `ba b3 e5 75 d2 9e bb d1 0e 20 85 ef 11 d4 12 d9 d0 09 6d b1`.